# Gmail inbox suddenly flooded with spam after years of successful blocking

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [More spam is making it into my gmail inbox - is it due to something I've done?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4612/more-spam-is-making-it-into-my-gmail-inbox-is-it-due-to-something-ive-done)

After years of using Gmail and having it block spam properly, earlier today I got dozens of spam messages in my inbox.

Is there a way to get Gmail's spam fighting back to normal? (Besides marking every spam message as spam, which would probably mean Gmail will take a long time to learn what's spam.)

Does anyone know why something like this would happen all of a sudden?

Answer (score 1):

Spam filters of any type are not static. As filters get better spammers devise new ways to get past them. What has most likely happened is that some spammer found a loophole that allowed its spam to get through.

The best (only) thing to do is to mark them all as spam so that Google can inspect them and improve its filters.